# Could not find file 'nssm.exe'

Tags: windows, ansible

I'm trying to autostart nginx from mac to windows2019 using ansible, but I get an error.

ansible [core 2.12.2]、
python version = 3.10.2

```
    - name: install nginx
      win_chocolatey:
        name: nginx
        version: 1.21.6
    - name: Transfer nginx.conf
      win_template:
        src: ./win/nginx/nginx.conf
        dest: C:\tools\nginx-1.21.6\conf\nginx.conf
    - name: install nssm
      win_chocolatey:
        name: nssm
        state: present
    - name: start nginx
      win_nssm:
        name: nginx
        application: C:\tools\nginx-1.21.6\nginx.exe
        app_parameters_free_form: -c C:\tools\nginx-1.21.6\conf\nginx.conf -p C:\tools\nginx-1.21.6
        stdout_file: C:\nginx_out.txt
        stderr_file: C:\nginx_error.txt
        start_mode: auto
        state: started
        notify:
          - start nginx
```

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was:    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()
fatal: [XX.XXX.XXX.XX]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unhandled exception while executing module: Exception calling \"SearchPath\" with \"1\" argument(s): \"Could not find file 'nssm.exe'.\""}
```

Sorry, it looks like you had to be an "Administrator" for the PATH to work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it looks like you had to be an "Administrator" for the PATH to work.

This worked.

```
- name: install nginx as service
  become: yes
  become_user: Administrator
  become_method: runas
  win_nssm:
    name: nginx
    application: C:\tools\nginx-1.21.6\nginx.exe
    app_parameters_free_form: -c C:\tools\nginx-1.21.6\conf\nginx.conf -p C:\tools\nginx-1.21.6
    stdout_file: C:\nginx_out.txt
    stderr_file: C:\nginx_error.txt
    start_mode: auto
    state: started
    notify:
      - start nginx
```